# Storing User Inputted Names In a Circular Linked Lists

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, user-input

I'm currently trying to make a program where I'll be able to input information (in this case the information will be names / strings) and have said information dynamically stored in a circular linked list. I wanna be able to delete nodes that have been created but right now I'm just stuck at the creation of the nodes in the first place so that'll come after. I'm still relatively new to this so the concepts are a bit abstract to me. I basically saw some code online with the same concept behind what I'm trying to do and tried figuring out what each sentence does so i'll better understand how to implement this but I'm still getting errors when I do so
The error i keep getting after I compile is that the "struct node has no member named children." But to my knowledge it's declared

Here's the code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 20 //char array size for names

struct node
{
char players[SIZE];
struct node *next;
}*firstnode;

void  createList(int amount);
void displayList();

int main()
{
char children[SIZE];
int amount; //stores the number of children that will be playing
firstnode = NULL;

printf(" Welcome To The Count Out Game!\n");    //Header
printf("------------------------------------\n\n");    //Header 

printf("How Many Children Will Be Playing? : ");
scanf("%d", &amount);

void createList(int amount)
    {
        int i;
        char children [SIZE];

        struct node *prevNode, *newNode;

        if(amount>=1)
            {
                firstnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

                printf("Enter The Name For Child 1: ");
                scanf("%s", &children);

                firstnode->children = children;
                firstnode->next= NULL;

                prevNode = firstnode;

                for(i=2; i<=amount; i++)
                    {
                        newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                        printf("Enter the name for child %d", i);
                        scanf("%s", &children);

                        newNode->children = children;
                        newNode->next = NULL;

                        prevNode->next = newNode;
                        prevNode = newNode;

                        prevNode->next = firstnode;
                    }
              }


    }

void displayList()
    {
        struct node *current;
        int n = 1;

        if(firstnode == NULL)
            {
                printf("List Is Empty");
            }

        else
            {
                current = firstnode;
                printf("Names Of Children In The List\n");

                do
                    {
                        printf("Names %s\n", n, current->firstnode);

                        current = current->next;
                        n++;
                    }
                while(current!= firstnode);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `main` function's `}`?

Comment: You probably wanted `scanf("%s", children);

                        strcpy(newNode->player, children);` and don't forget to `#include <string.h>` and `printf("Names %s\n", n, current->firstnode);` -> `printf("Name %d: %s\n", n, current->player);`

Comment: you have written the createlist method inside main

Comment: Yes, `struct node` is declared, but it has just two members — `players` and `next`; neither of those is spelled `children`, like the compiler says.  And you can't do string copying with assignment in C — you need `strcpy()` or something equivalent.

Comment: Moreover your code had many errors .Because you should use firstnode->players =children because node had char array players

Comment: @GaneshChowdharySadanala: You can't assign pointers to arrays.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler what do u mean

Comment: @GaneshChowdharySadanala: I mean that `firstnode->players = children;` won't compile.

Comment: yep it would be easier if you include string header file in your program and make players as string and also children as string ,so that firstnode->players =children would be easily done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182129/discussion-between-ganesh-chowdhary-sadanala-and-jonathan-leffler).

Comment: @GaneshChowdharySadanala: Well, you'd also have include `<stdlib.h>` and manage the strings as well as the nodes.  I think the array in the structure is perfectly appropriate.  We can debate about the (lack of) overflow checking, but that's an ever-present problem in C.

Comment: I appreciate the help but everyone keeps explaining things like I should understand what you're talking about. I'm relatively new to this, can you further simplify exactly what you're saying? and give advice on what approach I can use to solve the issue?

Comment: As noted in the chat session, which you visited, Ajay, you need to clean up your code to make something resembling an MCVE ([MCVE]).  With non-compilable code, people aren't all that inclined to work hard on your algorithmic problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, working on a singularly-linked (circular) linked list as an introduction to linked lists, takes a bit more thought and understanding than just a simple Head->Tail list where the `last->next` pointer is simply `NULL`. Take for example the *non-circular* list:

```
Singly Linked-List (non-circular)

             Node1                 Node2                 Node3
         +------------+        +------------+        +------------+
         |   Payload  |        |   Payload  |        |   Payload  |
         +------------+        +------------+        +------------+
         |   Next     |------->|   Next     |------->|   Next     |--->NULL
         +------------+        +------------+        +------------+
```

Above, simply *chaining* (hooking the nodes together via the `next` pointer is all that is needed while setting the `last->next` pointer to `NULL`. This makes adding to the list trivial as you can either simply add the new node as the new 1st node changing the list address each time, e.g.

```
list *newnode = malloc (sizeof *newnode);  /* validate, set data values, ... */
newnode->next = list;
list = newnode;
```

or you can simply iterate `while (node->next != NULL)` and then add the new node at the end, e.g.

```
node->next = newnode;
newnode->next = NULL;
```

A non-circular list has the advantage of simplicity, but it has the disadvantage of only being able to iterate from the beginning to the end of the list. You can't iterate from any node back to the node just before it from any point in the list. (this can make a big efficiency difference with large lists)

To solve this problem, a *circular* list has the `last->next` pointer point back to the beginning of the list. With this one addition, you can iterate from the `iter = current;` across the entire list `while (iter->next != current)` allowing you to iterate from any point in the list to any other point in the list without starting over at the beginning. That introduces just a bit of additional complexity. Think about it:

```
 Singly Linked-List (circular)

             Node1                 Node2                 Node3
         +------------+        +------------+        +------------+
         |   Payload  |        |   Payload  |        |   Payload  |
         +------------+        +------------+        +------------+
    +--->|   Next     |------->|   Next     |------->|   Next     |--->+
    |    +------------+        +------------+        +------------+    |
    |                                                                  |
    +<--------------------<---------------------<----------------------+
```

Now when adding nodes to the list you have a couple of special cases to insure you handle. For example when adding the first node, since the list is circular, the first node is *self-referential* (or self-referencing, for lack of better words), e.g.

```
Singly Linked-List (circular) - 1st Node is Self-Referencial

             Node1
         +------------+
         |   Payload  |
         +------------+
    +--->|   Next     |--->+
    |    +------------+    |
    |                      |
    +<---------------------+
```

This doesn't add a lot of complexity, but requires that you think a bit deeper about how you are adding nodes to the list and insuring that your `last->next` pointer always points back around to the beginning of the list. This also requires a bit more care in iterating over the list, because you iterate until the `current->next` pointer is equal to the starting point (usually the list address, but can be any node).

Starting your list learning with a circular list is fine, but you have to keep the pointers straight in your head. The best way to do that is simply pull out a pencil and draw out the nodes you are working on (much like the boxes I used as a diagram) and when you need to add a node, make sure you re-wire all the pointer correctly when you insert the new node in the list. The same works for deleting a node from the list. Use your eraser to get rid of it, and then code the re-wiring of the pointers to sew your list back together again.

Your code makes things harder than it needs to be by not using descriptive variable names (at least mixing *children* and *players* and *child*, etc... did not work well in my mind) Each node in your `struct` will hold a single `player`, not multiple `children`. Keeping the *singular* and *plural* forms of variable names straight goes a long way to help keep the logic straight. A bit of renaming, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXNM 32    /* avoid generic defines like SIZE (maxname?) */

typedef struct _node {
    char player[MAXNM];
    struct _node *next;
} node;
```

(**note:** simply making a `node` a `node` helps as well and there is no need to create a global pointer to `firstnode`. Instead just create a convenient `typedef` for use in your code.)

Then within `main()`, you would likewise use a buffer named `player` to hold the input you read from the user, e.g.

```
int main (void) {

    char player[MAXNM] = "";
    int nplayers = 0;
    node *list = NULL;
```

Just a side note, you don't need multiple `printf` statements to output multiple lines of text or to keep the text from wrapping off the side of your page. In C, quoted strings are concatenated. Additionally, while your compiler will probably make the change as an automatic optimization, if you have no *conversion specifiers* in your string, you might as well use `puts` or `fputs` and avoid calling a *variadic function* unless it is required. E.g.,

```
    fputs ( " Welcome To The Count Out Game!\n"
            "------------------------------------\n\n"
            "How Many Children Will Be Playing? : ", stdout );
```

(why use `fputs` here instead of `puts`? -- that is a good thing to go figure out...)

Next, you must ***validate*** all user input and handle any error that arise. Otherwise you will stray of into *Undefined Behavior* processing garbage and indeterminate values until very bad things happen to your program. While you are better served using `fgets` and then calling `sscanf` to parse the value (or `strtol`, etc..), `scanf` can be properly used if you at minimum ***check the return***. That way you can validate that at least the anticipated number of conversions took place and you have valid input in your variable:

```
    if (scanf ("%d", &nplayers) != 1 || nplayers < 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

But the pitfalls of using `scanf` is that it will leaving the trailing `'\n'` (generated by the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>) in the input buffer and you must handle that before taking input with `fgets` or an other non-numeric or other conversions specifier besides `"%s"` (which itself adds a whole other list of problems created by the fact it stops reading at the first whitespace - so if there are additional/accidental characters after a whitespace, you are in trouble)

So it is up to you to remove any additional characters that remain in your input buffer (`stdin` here). You can do that will a simply loop and `getchar()` (or `fgetc()` if reading from another open file stream), e.g.

```
    /* remove any additional characters from stdin */
    for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}
```

Which brings us to your input loop for the player names where you will call `insertnode` (or your `createList`) to begin adding nodes to your list (and showing the completion of `main()`)

```
    /* prompt for player and insert node in list */
    while (nplayers-- && 
            fputs ("name: ", stdout) != EOF && 
            fgets (player, MAXNM, stdin)) {
        player[strcspn (player, "\n")] = 0;     /* trim '\n' from end */
        if (!insertnode (&list, player))
            break;
    }

    displaylist (list);     /* output all players in list */
    freelist (list);        /* free list memory */

    return 0;
}
```

Note above where `insertnode (&list, player)` is called. You are passing the *address of* the list to your insert function. You do this so if the list address (i.e. the first node) changes, the new list address will be available back in the calling function. If you fail to pass the *address of* the list pointer, then you will need to return the list address from the function and assign it each time back in the calling function.

You also need to declare your function with a *meaningful return type* that can indicate **success/failure** of the insert operation. Simply returning a pointer to the node that was inserted on success is convenient, or `NULL` on failure is fine.

In your insert function, aside from validating `player` is not `NULL`, you need to determine if the list exists, and if not add the new node as the 1st node (setting the `next` pointer to point back to itself), --or-- you need to iterate to the end of the list and insert the new node there. Each time ensuring the `next` pointer points back to the list address. A simple implementation would be:

```
node *insertnode (node **list, char *player)
{
    /* validate player not NULL, handle error */
    if (!player)
        return NULL;

    /* allocate/validate new node */
    node *newnode = malloc (sizeof *newnode);
    if (!newnode) {
        perror ("malloc-newnode");
        return NULL;
    }
    /* copy player to node, initialize next NULL */
    strcpy (newnode->player, player);
    newnode->next = NULL;

    /* check whether list exists, or is this 1st node? */
    if (!*list) {
        newnode->next = newnode;    /* circular list is self-referencial */
        *list = newnode;
    }
    else {  /* list exist, find last node in circular list */
        node *iter = *list;         /* create pointer to iterate to end */
        for (; iter->next != *list; iter = iter->next) {}   /* iterate */
        iter->next = newnode;       /* insert as last node */
        newnode->next = *list;      /* circular, set next to *list */
    }

    return newnode;     /* return node as convenience & success/failure */
}
```

For whatever other functions you want to write for your list, it's just a matter of pulling out the pencil and working out how to iterate over the list to get the needed data from the list. As an example, you could provide a print list or `displaylist()` function as well as a function to free the memory associated with the list.

Pay attention to the subtleties of how the iteration is handled (in the case of the `freelist` function beginning deletion of the 2nd node to ensure the `last->next` pointer references a valid address to indicate the end of your iteration), e.g.

```
void displaylist (node *list)
{
    node *iter = list;

    /* iterate from first to last node, setting iter NULL after last */
    for (; iter; iter = (iter->next != list ? iter->next : NULL))
        puts (iter->player);
}

void freelist (node *list)
{
    node *victim = list->next,  /* free 2nd node 1st, leaving valid 1st */
        *next = NULL;

    while (victim != list) {    /* while victim isn't list address */
        next = victim->next;    /* save next address before free */
        free (victim);          /* free victim */
        victim = next;          /* assign next to victim */
    }

    free (victim);  /* free 1st node */
}
```

Putting it altogether, you would have something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXNM 32    /* avoid generic defines like SIZE (maxname?) */

typedef struct _node {
    char player[MAXNM];
    struct _node *next;
} node;

node *insertnode (node **list, char *player);
void displaylist (node *list);
void freelist (node *list);

int main (void) {

    char player[MAXNM] = "";
    int nplayers = 0;
    node *list = NULL;

    fputs ( " Welcome To The Count Out Game!\n"
            "------------------------------------\n\n"
            "How Many Children Will Be Playing? : ", stdout );

    if (scanf ("%d", &nplayers) != 1 || nplayers < 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    /* remove any additional characters from stdin */
    for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}

    /* prompt for player and insert node in list */
    while (nplayers-- && 
            fputs ("name: ", stdout) != EOF && 
            fgets (player, MAXNM, stdin)) {
        player[strcspn (player, "\n")] = 0;     /* trim '\n' from end */
        if (!insertnode (&list, player))
            break;
    }

    displaylist (list);     /* output all players in list */
    freelist (list);        /* free list memory */

    return 0;
}

node *insertnode (node **list, char *player)
{
    /* validate player not NULL, handle error */
    if (!player)
        return NULL;

    /* allocate/validate new node */
    node *newnode = malloc (sizeof *newnode);
    if (!newnode) {
        perror ("malloc-newnode");
        return NULL;
    }
    /* copy player to node, initialize next NULL */
    strcpy (newnode->player, player);
    newnode->next = NULL;

    /* check whether list exists, or is this 1st node? */
    if (!*list) {
        newnode->next = newnode;    /* circular list is self-referencial */
        *list = newnode;
    }
    else {  /* list exist, find last node in circular list */
        node *iter = *list;         /* create pointer to iterate to end */
        for (; iter->next != *list; iter = iter->next) {}   /* iterate */
        iter->next = newnode;       /* insert as last node */
        newnode->next = *list;      /* circular, set next to *list */
    }

    return newnode;     /* return node as convenience & success/failure */
}

void displaylist (node *list)
{
    node *iter = list;

    /* iterate from first to last node, setting iter NULL after last */
    for (; iter; iter = (iter->next != list ? iter->next : NULL))
        puts (iter->player);
}

void freelist (node *list)
{
    node *victim = list->next,  /* free 2nd node 1st, leaving valid 1st */
        *next = NULL;

    while (victim != list) {    /* while victim isn't list address */
        next = victim->next;    /* save next address before free */
        free (victim);          /* free victim */
        victim = next;          /* assign next to victim */
    }

    free (victim);  /* free 1st node */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

A short example of its use would be:

```
$ ./bin/ll-cir_players
Welcome To The Count Out Game!
------------------------------------

How Many Children Will Be Playing? : 5
name: Tom
name: Dick
name: Harry
name: Gus
name: Sarah
Tom
Dick
Harry
Gus
Sarah
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/ll-cir_players
==29803== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==29803== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==29803== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==29803== Command: ./bin/ll-cir_players
==29803==
Welcome To The Count Out Game!
------------------------------------

How Many Children Will Be Playing? : 5
name: Tom
name: Dick
name: Harry
name: Gus
name: Sarah
Tom
Dick
Harry
Gus
Sarah
==29803==
==29803== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29803==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29803==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 200 bytes allocated
==29803==
==29803== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==29803==
==29803== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==29803== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Now this ended up much longer than anticipated, but it was clear you were quite lost in understanding and approaching a *singly-linked-circular linked list*. Hopefully this will give you a basic understanding and let you build forward from here.